# Regex expression substring wildcard

Tags: c#, regex

In C# I'm trying to search for the substring "flight%sin" where %s would be a string. How would I do this using regex in c#?

Comment: did you want to match `%s`?

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex? Why not just use IndexOf?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You need to provide some more concrete examples and explain what you're trying to achieve. Also, you need to show what you've tried so far to solve the problem, and be sure to tell us what went wrong with your attempt (errors, unexpected results, etc.)

Comment: Sorry for it being unclear. I want to match for instance: "flight is coming in" - true;  "flight in" - true,  "in flight" - false. So basically in contains those two words in that order and can have any type of string in between

Comment: I do not want to match %s that was just supposed to be an arbitrary string of any length

Comment: To provide an update to your question, please use the *edit* link that appears below the question, just under the tags. And again, please show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the text between "flight" and "in" using `@"flight(\w+)in"`

The [reference guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides more detail.

Here is a Regex example in C#.

```
        string [] mystrings = new string [] {"flight%sin", "flightTest1sin", "flighNoGoodsin", "flightTest2sin"};
        foreach (string s in mystrings)
        {
            var groups = Regex.Match(s, @"flight(\w+)in");
            if (groups.Groups.Count > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(groups.Groups[1]);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: ok thanks! I'll try it tomorrow. Hopefully it works

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
string data = "flight 4057 in"; //I am guessing, this is what the original string will be.
public string getFlightNumber(string data)
{

int flightNumLength = 4;// Or however long the string would be

for(int index = 0; index < data.length(); index++)
{
   if(index+flightNumLength + index < data.length())  
   {
       string TempFlight = data.subSting(index, flightNumLength);
    if(isNumeric(TempFlight))
    {
         return TempFlight;
    }

   }
}
}


public static bool IsNumeric(object Expression){
    bool isNum;
    double retNum;

    isNum = Double.TryParse(Convert.ToString(Expression),     System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any,System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out retNum );
    return isNum; 
}
```